# $\kappa$ is compact $\implies$ $\kappa$ is regular

Tags: logic, set-theory, large-cardinals

**Definitions**

The Stanford Encylopedia of Philosophy makes the following definition in their article on Infinitary Logic https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-infinitary/

> Let κ be an infinite cardinal. A language L is said to be κ-compact (resp. weakly κ-compact) if whenever Δ is a set of L-sentences (resp. a set of L-sentences of cardinality ≤ κ) and each subset of Δ of cardinality < κ has a model, so does Δ. Notice that the usual compactness theorem for L is precisely the assertion that L is ω-compact.

> Let us call a cardinal κ compact if the language L(κ,κ) is κ-compact

Additionally, I define the cofinality of an ordinal to be the least ordertype of cofinal subsets.

Take the Axiom of Choice for granted.

**Question**

How can we show that a compact cardinal $\kappa$ must be regular?

My initial thought was to assume that, if not, then there is an increasing cofinal $f: \alpha \to \kappa$ where $\alpha= \operatorname{cf}(\kappa) < \kappa$. Then I was thinking of constructing a "creative" set of sentences $\{\phi_i\}_{i \in \alpha}$ and considering a corresponding set $\{\phi_{f(i)}\}_{i \in \alpha}$ and somehow taking advantage of satisfiability. I'm doubtful that this idea would work, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\kappa$ is singular, so we have $\kappa=\bigcup_{i<\alpha}A_i$ for some $\alpha<\kappa$ and some sets $A_i$ whose cardinalities are $<\kappa$. Let $p_\xi$ be a propositional variable for each ordinal $\xi<\kappa$, and consider the set $\Sigma$ of the following formulas: $\neg p_\xi$ for each $\xi<\kappa$ and the one additional formula $\bigvee_{i<\alpha}\big(\bigvee_{\xi\in A_i}p_\xi\big)$. Note that each of the disjunctions here has $<\kappa$ disjuncts, so all $\kappa$ of the  sentences in $\Sigma$ are in $L_{\kappa,\kappa}$ (in fact in $L_{\kappa,1}$ since no quantifiers are used). $\Sigma$ is not satisfiable because the one additional formula requires at least one $p_\xi$ to be true. But any subset of $\Sigma$ of size $<\kappa$ (indeed, any proper subset of $\Sigma$) is stisfiable.

Comment: I think I understand the gist of your proof. One technical issue that I'm having, however, is with the "propositional variables." The way my book defines formulae requires that a formula be either atomic (i.e. of the form $t_1=t_2$ or of the form $P(t_1, \cdots, t_n)$ ) or built up from atomic formulae. How do we resolve this?

Comment: @Pascal'sWager   Take each $p_\xi$ to be a $0$-ary predicate symbol (and, if you really insist on your notation, write $p_\xi(\ )$ instead of $p_\xi$).

Comment: I was thing of doing that, but the thing is that the language isn't required to have predicate symbols per se. If there's no predicate symbols, what do we do?

Comment: You can use equations between constant symbols instead.  (Just about any way of producing $\kappa$ formulas will do.)

Comment: Unfortunately, we might not have constant symbols or function symbols either (although we do have equality.)  I was thinking of trying to use formulae like $(\exists v_0)( \exists v_1)(\neg v_0 \neq v_1)$ for the $p_\xi$, but of course I can't just copy and paste the same exact formula for all the $p_\xi$ because otherwise they would be dependent on each other. Maybe there's a clever way to do with where $p_\xi$ involves $(\exists v_\beta)_{\beta < \xi}$?

Comment: If you restrict the language so badly that you can't produce $\kappa$ inequivalent formulas, then compactness trivially holds.

Comment: I don't understand. I see why $\Sigma$ would still be unsatisfiable, but I'm not sure that we can guarantee proper subsets would be satisfiable and so I don't know what to do

Comment: @Pascal'sWager Any proper subset either excludes the massive disjunction (in which case setting all $p_\xi$ to be false gives a model) or excludes one of the sentences $\lnot p_\xi$ (in which case setting $p_\xi$ to be true and all other $p_\alpha$ to be false gives a model).

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\kappa$ is singular, and let $(\alpha_i)_{i\in I}$ be a cofinal sequence of ordinals less than $\kappa$, with $|I|<\kappa$.

We will work in the language of strict order, $\{<\}$. Observe the following:

1. There is a sentence $\varphi$ of $L_{\kappa,\kappa}$ (even of $L_{\omega_1,\omega_1}$) axiomatizing the well-orders. Just take the conjunction of the first-order linear order axioms with a sentence asserting that there is no descending $\omega$-sequence.
2. For every ordinal $\alpha<\kappa$, there is a sentence $\theta_\alpha$ of $L_{\kappa,\kappa}$ such that for a well-order $M$, $M\models \theta_\alpha$ if and only if the order type of $M$ is $\geq \alpha$: $$\exists (x_\beta)_{\beta<\alpha} \bigwedge_{\beta<\beta'} x_\beta < x_{\beta'}$$

Now look at the set $\Delta$ consisting of $\varphi$, $\theta_\alpha$ for every $\alpha<\kappa$, and the sentence $$\bigvee_{i\in I} \lnot\theta_{\alpha_i}.$$
Every subset of $\Delta$ of size $<\kappa$ has a model, but $\Delta$ has no model, so $L_{\kappa,\kappa}$ is not $\kappa$-compact. Since $|\Delta|=\kappa$, $L_{\kappa,\kappa}$ is not even weakly $\kappa$-compact.