# Compact cardinal cannot be successor?

Tags: logic, set-theory, cardinals, large-cardinals

This is a follow-up question to [$\kappa$ is compact $\implies$ $\kappa$ is regular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4319718/kappa-is-compact-implies-kappa-is-regular). The definition I'm using for "compact" is the same as there.

I am trying to show if $\kappa$ is compact, then $\kappa$ cannot be a successor cardinal.

My first attempt was as follows: Assume $\kappa=\lambda^+$. Let $\{p_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \kappa}$ be propositional variables, and let $p$ be $\bigvee_{\beta \in \lambda} p_\alpha$. Then the set of sentences $\Sigma=\{\neg p_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \kappa} \cup \{p\}$ is obviously unsatisfiable, because if $p$ is true then at least some $p_\alpha$ must be true. Then, trying to reach the desired contradiction, I tried to show that any subset of $\Sigma$ having cardinality $< \kappa$ is satisfiable, but I realized this is false. (For example, $\{\neg p_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \lambda} \cup \{p\}$ has size $\lambda < \kappa$ but it is not satisfiable.)

Perhaps there's a more creative way to pick $\Sigma$ which actually works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll show something stronger: If $L_{\kappa,\omega}$ is $\kappa$-compact, then $\kappa$ is a *strong* limit. The result of your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4319718/7062) showed that $\kappa$ is regular, so we conclude that $\kappa$ is strongly inaccessible.

Assume $\kappa$ is not a strong limit, i.e., there exists $\lambda<\kappa$ such that $2^\lambda\geq \kappa$. Work in the language with proposition symbols $\{P_\alpha\mid \alpha<\lambda\}$, and consider the $L_{\kappa,\omega}$-theory $T$: $$\left\{\lnot\left(\bigwedge_{\alpha\in X}P_\alpha\land \bigwedge_{\alpha\notin X}\lnot P_\alpha\right)\,\middle\vert\, X\subseteq \lambda \right\}.$$
Note that each conjunction in $T$ is over a set of size $\leq \lambda < \kappa$. $T$ is unsatisfiable, because it explicitly rules out any assignment of truth values to the $P_\alpha$. But $|T| = 2^\lambda \geq \kappa$, so any subset of $T$ of size $<\kappa$ is a proper subset of $T$, which is satisfiable.

---

Of course, in the argument above, it is possible that $|T|>\kappa$, so the argument does not go through if we only assume $L_{\kappa,\omega}$ is *weakly* $\kappa$-compact (meaning that $\kappa$-compactness only applies to theories of size $\leq \kappa$).

If $L_{\kappa,\omega}$ is only weakly $\kappa$-compact, we can stil prove that $\kappa$ is a limit cardinal; hence, since $\kappa$ is regular, $\kappa$ is weakly inaccessible. My [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4321293/7062) gave a proof of this  following the hint given by Jech in Exercise 17.17 of *Set Theory (Third Millennium Edition)*. [Jonathan's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4321879/7062) shows that the idea can be dramatically simplified. And here's an even simpler version:

Assume $\kappa = \lambda^+$. Work in the language with constants $\{c_\alpha\mid \alpha<\kappa\}$ and $\{d_\gamma\mid \gamma<\lambda\}$. Consider the following $L_{\kappa,\omega}$-theory $T$: $$\{c_\alpha\neq c_\beta\mid \alpha< \beta<\kappa\}\cup \{\forall x\,\bigvee_{\gamma<\lambda} x = d_\gamma\}$$
$T$ is not satisfiable, because the schema $c_\alpha\neq c_\beta$ implies that the size of a model is $\geq \kappa$, while the sentence $\forall x\,\bigvee_{\gamma<\lambda} x = d_\gamma$ ensures that the size of a model is $\leq \lambda$. But any subset $T'\subseteq T$ with $|T'|<\kappa$ only asserts that at most $\lambda$-many of the constants $c_\alpha$ are distinct, so $T'$ admits a model of cardinality $\lambda$.

---

So the natural question is: does *weak* $\kappa$-compactness of $L_{\kappa,\kappa}$ imply that $\kappa$ is a *strong* limit (and hence strongly inaccessible?). I didn't know the answer, but according to the comments to [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/337392/2126), the answer is no. Apparently the result is due to Solovay and Kunen, and a proof is given in the paper [Infinitary compactness without strong inaccessibility](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2272942) by William Boos.

Note that many sources define "weakly compact cardinal" in such a way that weakly compact cardinals are strongly inaccessible. For example, Jech says a cardinal $\kappa$ is weakly compact if it is uncountable and $\kappa\to (\kappa)^2$, and this definition implies that $\kappa$ is a strong limit. Then he proves (Theorem 17.13) that *if $\kappa$ is (strongly) inaccessible* and the logic $L_{\kappa,\omega}$ is weakly compact, then $\kappa$ is weakly compact.

Comment: I presume that $k\to (k)^2$ means $k\to (k)^2_2$. An old result of Erdos et al is that $\neg [2^{\ell}\to (\ell^+)^2_2],$ so if $k\to (k)^2_2$ then $k$ is a strong limit.

Answer (score 3):

This strategy is taken from the hint in Jech, Exercise 17.17. Suppose $\kappa = \lambda^+$.

We work in the language with constant symbols $\{c_\alpha\mid \alpha\leq \kappa\}$, a binary relation $<$, and a ternary relation $R$. Consider the following theory $T$:

1. The sentence "$<$ is a linear order".
2. The schema $c_\alpha<c_\beta$ for all $\alpha<\beta\leq \kappa$.
3. The sentence "For all $x$, $R(x,y,z)$ is the graph of a function $f_x(y) = z$."
4. The sentence $\forall x\forall z(z<x\rightarrow \exists y\, R(x,y,z))$. This expresses that the range of $f_x$ contains the initial segment $\{z\mid z<x\}$.
5. The infinitary sentence $\forall x\forall y\forall z\, (R(x,y,z)\rightarrow \bigvee_{\alpha<\lambda} y = c_\alpha)$. This expresses that the domain of $f_x$ is contained in $\{c_\alpha\mid \alpha<\lambda\}$.

Now $T$ is inconsistent, since we must have $|\text{dom}(f_{c_\kappa})|\leq \lambda$ but $|\text{ran}(f_{c_\kappa})|\geq \kappa$ (since it contains $\{c_\alpha\mid \alpha < \kappa\}$).

Let $T'\subset T$ be a subset with $|T'|<\kappa$. Then $T'$ only contains $\lambda$-many of the sentences $c_\alpha<c_\beta$, so it only mentions at most $\lambda$-many of the constant symbols. Take $M$ to be the set of constant symbols mentioned in $T'$: the symbosl $\{c_\alpha\mid \alpha<\lambda\}$ mentioned in axiom (5), together with any of the constant symbols $c_\beta$ with $\beta\geq \lambda$ which are mentioned by instances of schema (2). We interpret the remaining constant symbols arbitrarily, say setting them all to be equal to $c_0$. We equip the model with its natural order, induced from the ordering on the indices of the constant symbols (its order type will be some ordinal $\xi$ with $\lambda \leq \xi < \kappa$). It remains to define the function $f_x$ for each element $x$. Note that $\{z\mid z<x\}$ has size $\leq \lambda$, since $|M| = \lambda$. So we can define $f_x$ to be an arbitrary function from $\{c_\alpha\mid \alpha<\lambda\}$ onto $\{z\mid z<x\}$ (unless $\{z\mid z<x\}$ is empty, in which case we can take $f_x$ to be the empty function).

We conclude that $L_{\kappa,\kappa}$ (stronger, $L_{\kappa,\omega}$) is not weakly compact.

Comment: Is it possible that $\kappa$ is $not$ a strong limit cardinal?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Your comment spurred me to investigate this a bit more, see my [new answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4322125/7062).

Answer (score 2):

Assume $\kappa = \lambda^+$.

Consider a language which has constants $\langle c_\alpha : \alpha < \kappa \rangle$ and one function symbol $f$. Let $T$ be a theory containing

- A sentence expressing that $f$ is a bijection: $$\forall y \exists! x (f(x) = y),$$
- for each $\alpha < \kappa$, a sentence expressing that $f^{-1}(c_\alpha) = c_\beta$ for some $\beta < \lambda$. Namely, $$ \forall x (f(x) = c_\alpha \rightarrow \bigvee_{\beta < \lambda} x = c_\beta ). $$
- for each $\alpha, \beta < \kappa$, a sentence expressing that $c_\alpha \neq c_\beta$.

It is clear that this is unsatisfiable since in any model $f$ restricted to the first $\lambda$ many constants induces a bijection between $\lambda$ and $\kappa = \lambda^+$. But any subtheory of size $< \kappa$, i.e. of size $\leq \lambda$, mentions at most $\lambda$ many constants. To get a model it suffices to use a bijection between the first $\lambda$ many coordinates and $\lambda$ many constants including those that appear in our subtheory.

Comment: FYI. Alex Kruckman has given 2 answers. In his 2nd one he uses your A to give further results.